# Append +1 to phone number field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to format my phone number field correctly and I have it almost done.

I was able to use this script to add dashes in the phone number but how can I also add "+1" to the front of the phone number when all 10 numbers have been typed?

```
$('#tel').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3'))
});
```

Comment: If `+1` isn't variable, why does it need to be added to the beginning of the input? Maybe put it in a span beside the input to indicate it is static. This will also prevent your input text jumping when the user keys the last digit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first suggest that you replace the [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event with [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) (which has [IE 10+ support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event)) if at all possible.  Next, you should rework your filter to get the true numeric value first.  Then work your regex against that.  In my example I replaced non-10-digit-numbers with dash separated values, trimmed any resulting trailing dashes, and replaced a full 10-digit-value with the same value and a `+1` at the beginning.

```js
$('#tel').on('input', function(){
    var filteredValue = this.value.replace('+1 ', '').match(/\d*/g).join('');
    $(this).val(filteredValue
      .replace(/(\d{0,3})\-?(\d{0,3})\-?(\d{0,4}).*/,'$1-$2-$3')
      .replace(/\-+$/, '')
      .replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'+1 $1-$2-$3'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=tel>
```

Here's a simplified version closer to your original that only makes the replacement at the end of having 10 digits.

```js
$('#tel').on('input', function(){
    var filteredValue = this.value.replace('+1 ', '').match(/\d*/g).join('');
    $(this).val(filteredValue
      .replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4}).*/,'+1 $1-$2-$3'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=tel>
```

Comment: The answer below seems to still be working in my IE. Can't find a place where it wasn't working but I like your suggestion of filteredValue. It's much cleaner. Thank you, works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a callback to add `+1` when the number is ten digits or more, and remove the prefix and hyphens when under ten digits etc

```js
$('#tel').on('keyup', function(){
 if (this.value.replace(/\D/g,'').length > 9) {
      if (this.value.indexOf('-') === -1) {
       this.value = '+1' + this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3');
      }
    } else if ( this.value.indexOf('-') !== -1 ) {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/(\+1|-)/g,'');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tel">
```

Comment: This solution did work exactly as I needed. Another response said keyup doesnt have IE support, that may be the only issue with this.

Comment: @cgrouge - no, the other answer says that the `input` event is supported from IE10, and that you should change to that, which btw is not really the case, it's supported from IE11 and up. The `keyup` event is supported in **all** browsers, but does not catch pasted content etc. just keystrokes.

Comment: @cgrouge adeneo is correct in pointing out that I didn't say `keyup` is not supported.  The key difference between the two events is that `keyup` listens for a physical key being released, which strongly indicates that the value has changed.  `input` on the other hand is an event that fires when the value property of an input has changed.  There are several advantages to listening for that event over listening for `keyup`.  I will clarify, however, that the `input` event is supported in IE 10.  It's also partially supported in IE 9 (no support for when text is deleted. e.g. cut or backspace).